# Sending events to multiple clients

Tags: architecture, publish-subscribe

I need to send events to multiple clients.  Currently I am using a Pub-Sub\Observer pattern based solution implemented in WCF using named pipes.

If I want to send the events to a Webserver or a Linux machine, my solution will not work.  What are my options for a more generic solution?

Answer (score 2):

I like http://redis.io/ for my pubsub needs, it's multi-platform, lots of languages support it, very easy to tie into, and fast as hell. Redis is also a key/value storage engine, and has some other handy data storage functions, so you might find other uses for it for exchanging more permanent data between your windows and linux processes.

If you're looking for even more performance, there's also http://www.zeromq.org/ which will get you a very flexible and powerful messaging fabric layer to work with, but for most things it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that a messaging server or an enterprise service bus is what you need, assuming that you are willing to move away from WCF and names pipes.

Messaging servers are usually pretty agnostic about platforms, and there are several open and free alternatives available, such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com), [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) and [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org) (which hexist recommended in another answer). These servers (question of definition when it comes to ZeroMQ) provide several different means of integration using messages, including pub/sub.

Enterprise services buses are usually more complex, but are also more flexible. They usually support message transformation, complex routing and even orchestration. There are also a few different open and free alternatives here, such as [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/), [Apache Synapse](http://synapse.apache.org/) and [Mass Transit](http://masstransit-project.com/).

I haven't used all of the above alternatives, but I think that RabbitMQ could suit your need if you only are looking for messaging, and if you also need some nifty service bus features, add MassTransit (written in .NET).

Comment: I can add that the book "Enterprise Integration Patterns" is an excellent reference on the topic of generic and robust integration patterns.